# Calculating integral value of Fourier series

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

Given fourier series:
$$\mathrm{S}\left(x\right) =
{3 \over \pi}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
{\sin\left(\left[2n + 1\right]x\right) \over 2n + 1}\,,\qquad
\left\langle -\pi,\pi\right\rangle
$$
Evaluate: $\displaystyle{%
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\mathrm{f}\left(x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x}$.

I suppose that Parseval's identity should be used somehow to calculate this. 
I only know how to calculate sum using Parseval, don't know how to apply it to find value of an integral. 
Any help would be welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

Why Parseval? It is way easier than that: the integral of an odd integrable function over a symmetric interval with respect to the origin is just zero.

Comment: but what would happen if I had to evaluate, for example $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)sin(3x)dx$? Would I have to use Parseval then? And how would I use it?

Comment: What do you know about the integrals $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin(nx)\sin(mx)\,dx$ ? Try to figure the answer by yourself, it is not difficult.

Comment: Is  f(x) supposed to equal S(x), otherwise the question makes no sense